# how to get the amount of dns servers worldwide?

Tags: dns, traversal, calculator

As we know DNS server must serve at 53 port, so I have the most slow way to get the whole amount, it's to get all the Ipv4 addresses telneted at 53 port, but I'm sure this should be a very time-consuming process and deprecate it.

Does anybody have a better method than mine to achieve that.

Comment: Perhaps statistically - get a large number of domain names and query the DNS to find out which servers are used and count them, and then scale this up to the number of registered domains? Probably not very accuruate but might be more practical than trying every address on the internet. Plus what about servers on ipv6, are you not interested in those?

Comment: Thanks.Ipv6 is even larger, so I did not mention it. You are right, it's not clever to get all the addressed tried not to mention take Ipv6 into account.But statistically, I think it can not guarantee the accuracy due to the development of Internet in different regions, and I think if take this problem statistically, it's not my initial purpose.

Comment: i think this question should be moved to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks.Any differences between stackoverflow and serverfault?

Comment: 1. You interested in authoritative or recursive servers ? 2. What you do regarding multiple servers on a single IP ? 3. What about private servers ? 4. Every ADSL router is a DNS server. 5. Why you need it at all ?! It's not possible to answer your question unless you clearly specify your goals.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.I wanna write a report about authoritative and recursive servers distribution in the world, covering the volume, software, version, dnssec enabled or not, etc. It's not necessary to take private servers into consideration I think.